# Prepend text to file without creating a line break with SaltStack

Tags: salt-stack

I am using saltstack to managed configuration on my servers. I have a use case where I need to prepend text to the beginning of the file WITHOUT creating a line break.

Currently:

`/path/to/file:
  file.prepend:
    - text:
      here is some text to add`

This works great ACCEPT for the fact that "here is some text to add" is added on a new line at the top of the file. I need this text to be prepended at the beginning of the file without creating a new line break. I would love to do this with saltstack but I cannot find a solution to this problem anywhere in their documentation.

The text being added on a new line at the beginning of the file creates things to not work as expected. I have found a few examples of how to do this using sed or a bash script but would love to be able to use saltstack to accomplish this.

Has anyone experiences this same problem that can point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to come up with a solution for this using pattern matching and replacing.

```
add_text_to_start:
  file.replace:
    - name: /path/to/the/file
    - pattern: text that will always be at the beginning
    - repl: here is some text to add text that will always be at the beginning
```

The text that is at the beginning of the file will always be at the beginning of the file. So by matching the pattern I am able to add text to the beginning of the file without having to add a line break. All the rest of the text that follows the "text that will always be at the beginning of" is untouched and will be in the same place that is was in before the pattern find and replace occurred.